# Several calls to a tensor without re-reading

Tags: python, tensorflow

Situation: relatively few, relatively large training files, processing happens only on small parts of it at a time.

Goal: Reading a small batch of the large files once, process in parts without getting the next piped item.

The following should be the relevant extracts from my code:

```
filename_queue = (...)
reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
feature_list = [tf.parse_single_example(
        reader.read(filename_queue)[1],
        features={...}) for _ in range(batch_size)]  # Result: list of binary information
parsed_features = [tf.reshape(
        tf.cast(tf.decode_raw(features['data_raw'], tf.float64),
                tf.float32), [-1, num_cols]) for features in
                  feature_list]  # Result: List of Tensors
training_batch = tf.stack(
        [parsed_features[i][starts_used[i]:ends_used[i]:1, :]
         for i in range(self.batch_size)], 0,
        name="stack_features")  # Result: Stacked extracts from the list of Tensors
```

The idea is to go through different values for `starts_used` and `ends_used` before getting the new `features_list`. However, as it is, calls to `training_batch` seem to trigger the reader every time.

Question: How to freeze the value of `parsed_features` temporarily? I tried putting the parsing into a separate function, but that did not help.

(Non-essential Background: I try to perform classification using RNNs on very long sequences (of varying sizes). Rather than calculating the gradients on one complete sequence (which is *very* slow) I try truncated backprop, passing the final states as the initial state of the next round. Therefore the sequences should only be reloaded once all of them have been completely processed.)

**Edit:**
What seems to work is using non-trainable constant variables rather than tensors in the `training_batch` that I re-initialize every time I am done with the analysis, but this seems like a rather hacky solution. One problem of this solution is, that the initialisation is unclear: If i start the queue runners before `init_op`, the `init_op` trows an error ("FIFOQueue '_2_input_producer' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)"), if I do the `init_op` before, it just hangs forever (as it requires values from the reader).